# Using a Grails "g:sortableColumn" to sort by the size of a "hasMany" (many to one) property?

Tags: grails

is it possible to use the Grails "g:sortableColumn" tag to sort by a domain class "hasMany" property count?

```
class Book { hasMany = [authors: User]}
```

I want to sort all Books by the number of authors with a "g:sortableColumn" tag in my view, but how? Realy not possible?

Thanks and best regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best solution, but one

http://www.pubbs.net/200904/grails/65695-grails-user-sort-by-one-to-many-count-with-gorm-or-criteria.html

I thought there was a way to do it with criteriaBuilder but I cannot seem to make it work without changing your domain object

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I hoped that there is a better way to do this in grails....

Comment: The link containing the solution you suggest is no longer available, can you provide a snippet of code or another link? Thanks :)